# Show Results not in joining table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have three tables:

1. children
2. activities
3. signupActivity

Table 'children' contains details of children.

Table 'activities' contains details of an activity.

When a child signs up for an activity an entry is added to the table with the activityID and childID. I am trying to get a list of children that haven't signed up to an activity. I have tried the following query but I am getting an error:

"Not unique table/alias: 'children'"

```
SELECT children.childrenEmailAddress
FROM children 
    INNER JOIN activities ON signupActivity.SignupActivityID = activities.activityID
    INNER JOIN children ON signupActivity.signupActivitychildID = children.childrenID
LEFT JOIN signupActivity ON children.childrenID = signupActivity.signupActivitychildID
WHERE activities.activityID = 8
```

The recordset would also need to include a result based on joining a 'section' in the tables Children and Activity. children.childrenSection = activities.activitySection as well as filtering the recordset by activities.activityID

This was the final that I adapted from Arth:

```
 SELECT c.childrenEmailAddress
     FROM children c
     JOIN activities a
       ON a.activitySection = c.childrenSection
        AND a.activityID = 8
LEFT JOIN signupActivity sa 
       ON sa.signupActivitychildID = c.childrenID
    WHERE sa.signupActivitychildID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `LEFT JOIN` and a `NULL` check

```
   SELECT c.childrenEmailAddress
     FROM children c
LEFT JOIN signupActivity sa 
       ON sa.signupActivitychildID = c.childrenID
      AND sa.SignupActivityID = 8
    WHERE sa.signupActivitychildID IS NULL
```

Personally I'm not a fan of repeating the table name in each of the column names.. I find it unnecessary and frustrating to work with. Your query could be as simple as:

```
   SELECT c.emailAddress
     FROM child c
LEFT JOIN signupActivity sa 
       ON sa.childId = c.id 
      AND sa.activityID = 8
    WHERE sa.childId IS NULL
```

**UPDATE**

```
   SELECT c.childrenEmailAddress
     FROM children c
     JOIN activities a
       ON a.activitySection = c.childrenSection
      AND a.activityID = 8
LEFT JOIN signupActivity sa 
       ON sa.signupActivitychildID = c.childrenID
      AND sa.signupActivityactivityID = a.activityID
    WHERE sa.signupActivitychildID IS NULL
```

Comment: I have tried your second option but needed to filter the recordset by Activity ID. I get zero results.

Comment: SELECT childrenEmailAddress
     FROM children AS c
LEFT JOIN signupActivity AS sa 
       ON sa.signupActivitychildID = c.childrenID
    WHERE sa.signupActivitychildID IS NULL AND sa.SignupActivityID = 8

Comment: @DarylT my first solution should work as written (the commented out line goes above the WHERE as it is part of the LEFT JOIN)

Comment: @DarylT my second solution requires the database structure and column names to be changed

Comment: @DarylT I have removed the commenting as it appears it wasn't helpful!

Comment: Arth - we are getting there! You have managed to do what I asked but unfortunately I have overlooked the fact that I also need to filter the record by the section that the child is in and that the activity is for. For example childrenSection should equal activitySection in the table Activities

Comment: Thanks Arth! I needed to move the AND up but it works now!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Childeren C1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
           signupActivity S1
        WHERE
           S1.activityID= 8 AND
           C1.ChildID= S1.ChildID)
```

Comment: I'm not sure `signupActivity` contains `childrenEmailAddress`. Plus `SELECT *` in the subquery is overkill, `SELECT 1` will suffice.

Comment: There isnt a column childrenEmailAddress in S1 so this wouldnt work.

Comment: so could you please provide us with columns in S1?

Comment: ActiityID, ChildID, Status, Key

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `children` c
WHERE c.childID NOT IN(
SELECT `childID`
FROM `activities`);
```

Comment: I would need to filter this by activityID

Comment: How can you filter a child by activityID unless he is signed up to an activity?